# Extra brackets around inserted images

Tags: bug, images

Lately when I've insert an image (last two days in two different SE sites), I get

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

instead of

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

I've been manually editing the former into the latter. It is a bug or feature I'm not realizing?

I'm using the click-to-upload option if that matters.