# Update markdown help to reflect new uploaded image behavior

Tags: feature-request, editing-help

I recently got confused by the [new extra brackets around uploaded images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263976/extra-brackets-around-inserted-images). The [markdown help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images), where I looked, didn't cover it explicitly. (You can puzzle it out by checking the linking section.)

I think since this is the default behavior for uploaded images it would be good to show it in the help, at least in the "More" section.

Old upload behavior and what the help shows:

```
![text][1]
```

New upload behavior not shown explicitly in the help:

```
[![text][1]][1]
```